# openstreetmap response - importance and place_rank fields

Tags: geocoding, openstreetmap

What is the meaning of the 'importance' and 'place_rank' fields in a openstreetmap response ? I can't find it anywhere in the documentation :/

For example the response of this url:

```
http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q=135+pilkington+avenue,+birmingham&format=xml&polygon=1&addressdetails=1
```

is:

`<place place_id="62311100" osm_type="way" osm_id="90394480" place_rank="30" ...OMISSIS... importance="0.701">`

In the above response I have removed all the XML part I'm not interested in.

Comment: The results come from software called Nominatim, source code here https://github.com/twain47/Nominatim - however, I can't see any documentation along with it that would answer your question!

Comment: I have found this table for the [place_rank](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim/Development_overview#Country_to_street_level). But still no clue about **importance**

Answer (score 6):

As far as I know:

- The *importance* is used for ordering search results according to their relevance. The importance value is calculated/estimated using various attributes including the place's popularity on Wikipedia and its *rank*.
- The *rank* is based on a rather complex algorithm taking the place type and various other attributes into account. For example it seems checks whether this object is a village, a city, a country, a continent, a highway, a lake and similar other properties.

Unfortunately these attributes lack proper documentation. So all you can do is try to look at [Nominatim's source code](https://github.com/twain47/Nominatim) if you need more detailed information. From there I tried to extract the information mentioned above.